# LESS CSS preview no longer generated in VS 2013 Update 2 with Web Essentials 2.0

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I updated to VS 2013 Update 2 and Web Essentials 2.0. Now, all of my LESS documents no longer show a CSS preview, even when saving. I see no indication of errors.

It seems to come down to it breaking on certain selectors. I've noticed that, in some cases, "div.test a" will break it, but "div.test > a" doesn't. I haven't fully tested it, but this worked completely fine before. I had a handful of selectors that combined scope on one line (e.g., "div.my-class p { ... }"), which is perfectly valid. I have a LOT of styling, so I would really hate to spend company time converting it just because the editor is picky.

While it does seem to create the parsed CSS file in the directory, the preview of it does not show on the right side. I'd hate to uninstall the updates. Any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: here is a link to a LESS file that is having issues. I can run it through an online LESS=>CSS parser and it works fine, as it did before in VS, but now fails with WE 2.0. http://dailyappreminder.com/content/css/main.less

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it's an error in WebEssentials 2.0 release build. [This will help](http://vswebessentials.com/download#nightly) you to install nightly build that has fix for the issue. For me it works fine after a nightly build was installed.

Comment: BTW, version 2.1 was released and seems to fix the issue.